# Ensure parameter is an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to find a way to check whether a function parameter is an array or not. If it is not, turn it into an array and perform a function on it, otherwise just perform a function on it.

Example:

```
interface employee {
    first: string,
    last: string
}

function updateEmployees (emp: employee | employee[]) {
    let employees = [];
    if (emp instanceof Array) employees = [emp];
    else employees = emp;
    employees.forEach(function(e){
        return 'something'
    })
}
```

This seems like it would work to me but is throwing a warning of `Type 'employee' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'employee'.`

Comment: You switched around the `if` / `else`

Comment: This kind of polymorphism is a bad idea in general. Just make `updateEmployees` take an array. If you want to call it with a single employee, then do so with `updateEmployees([emp])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the fixed version of your function:

```
function updateEmployees (emp: employee | employee[]) {
    let employees: employee[] = [];
    if (emp instanceof Array) employees = emp;
    else employees = [emp];
    employees.forEach(function(e){
        return 'something'
    })
}
```

But it can be shorter:

```
function updateEmployees(emp: employee | employee[]) {
    (emp instanceof Array ? emp : [emp]).forEach(function(e){
        return 'something'
    })
}
```

Comment: Or even `[].concat(emp).forEach(...`.

Comment: @user663031 Improving the answer: `[].concat(emp || [])` would also handle null `emp` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typesafe function that ensures an array, (using Typescript).  It also checks to see if the item is `null` or `undefined`, and returns empty array if so, instead of adding it to an array.

```
function ensureArray<T>(value: T | T[]): T[] {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value
  } else if (value === undefined || value === null) {
    return []
  } else {
    return [value]
  }
}
```

If you DO want an array that contains null or undefined:

```
function ensureArray<T>(value: T | T[]): T[] {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value
  } 
  else {
    return [value]
  }
}
```

For your example, the usage would be:

```js
function updateEmployees (emp: employee | employee[]) {
    ensureArray(emp).forEach(function(e){
        return 'something'
    })
}
```

Notice that a `null` or `undefined` element will not create a runtime error using the additional check.  And the item in your loop is now of type 'employee'.